# How can I get number of active connections?

Tags: java, netty

Is it real to get a number of active connections to your server?
I wrote a simple http server and I need to know how many active connections does he have.

I tried this but it gives me wrong result after 10000 requests

```
@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super.channelInactive(ctx);
    StatusData.decreaseConnectionCounter();
}
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super.channelActive(ctx);
    log.info("Channel " + ctx.channel() + " is now active");
    StatusData.increaseConnectionCounter();
}
```

I change my class so it's look like this StatusData and when I generating 10000 requests in 100 threads it counts correctly.

```
class StatusData{

private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public void increaseConnectionCounter() {
        synchronized (counter){
        int newValue = counter.intValue() + 1;
        counter.set(newValue);
        }
    }

    public void decreaseConnectionCounter() {
        synchronized (counter){
        int newValue = counter.intValue() - 1;
        counter.set(newValue);
        }
    }

    public int getActiveConnectionCounter() {
        return counter.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using an `AtomicInteger` inside StatusData?

Comment: Now I user AtomicInteger, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks correct. It's most likely a bug in StatusData, like not use AtomicLong.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I found a problem